# slurm job name in a for loop

Tags: linux, bash, slurm, sbatch

I would like to have my job name function of the parameters of the loop.

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH -n 4
#SBATCH -p batch576

MAXLEVEL=8
process_id=$!
for Oh in '0.0001' '0.0005'
do
    for H in '1.' '0.8'
    do
        mkdir half$Oh$H
        cp half h.py RP.py `pwd`/half$Oh$H/
        cd half$Oh$H
        srun --mpi=pmi2 -J half${Oh}${H} ./half $Oh $H $MAXLEVEL &
        cd ..
    done
done
wait $process_id
```

Instead of test_min i would like : half0.00011. half0.00010.8 ....

```
squeue
             JOBID PARTITION     NAME     USER ST       TIME  NODES NODELIST(REASON)
               658  batch576 test_min  XXX  R       0:06      1 no de1-ib2
```

Do you have any ideas ?
Thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're submitting this job using sbatch, it will be a single job with multiple job steps. The `-J` option in srun names the jobsteps in your Job, not  the job itself. And by default, `squeue` does not show job step information. Try the `--steps` paramater for `squeue` to show the job step names.

Comment: Yes thanks you, It's works, sorry for the late reply.